# Why my car Over consume coolant .no any visible leak

Tags: coolant

I  have added almost 4 liters of coolant today in my car.but over heating,boiling coolant and indicating  low oil pressure alarm on the dashbod.what should be a problem

Answer (score 3):

There are generally 3 places for coolant to go:

1. Out of the system and onto the ground.
2. Into the oil system.
3. Into the combustion chamber and out the tailpipe.

It appears that #1 is not the issue as this is usually obvious. But check carefully anyway as it may be dripping onto the exhaust and being vaporized. You should smell the coolant in this case and may hear a hissing noise as it hits the hot exhaust.

#2 can usually be spotted by having a milky froth under the oil fill cap. This needs IMMEDIATE attention as the coolant will sink to the bottom of the oil pan and be pumped into the oil system instead of actual oil. Your engine can be severely damaged in a very short time!!

#3 can often be detected by seeing white smoke out the exhaust sometimes with a smell of coolant. But the definitive test is an exhaust gas analyzer.

Both 2 and 3 can be caused by a head gasket or more serious problems like a cracked block or head, or a warped block or cylinder head.

A history of overheating can cause any of the above. A head gasket problem can sometimes happen all on its own.

Comment: I will have it checked tomorrow.